# How to Make Top (or Bottom) Rounded Rectangle Corners in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

So the Rectangle control has RadiusX and RadiusY property for making rounded corners. However, this affects ALL corners but I'd like to know if there's a way to just affect the top corners, or the bottom corners, etc. Is there a way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [Border control CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius(v=VS.100).aspx) property:

```
  <Grid Width="100" Height="100">  
  <Border 
  BorderBrush="SlateBlue" 
  BorderThickness="5,10,15,20" 
  Background="Tomato" Padding="5"
  CornerRadius="5,10,15,20">
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" />
  </Border>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay two rectangle, one on top of the other. On the bottom rectangle, set the RadiusX and RadiusY properties, on the top rectangle keep them unset and then move it over the rounded top or bottom.

Make them the same color and it will look like a single rectangle with only the top or bottom rounded.

Comment: Unless there's some underlying reason why you'd have to use a rectangle overlaying another rectangle, the Border control is suited for controlling each corner's radius via the CornerRadius property.

Comment: There is: the border won't scale with the control (unless that is desired).